# Feed one or more initial positions to scipy.optimize.differential_evolution

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

Say I want to use [scipy.optimize.differential_evolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) to optimize a function, but I have a reasonable starting point where I believe the minimum is located.

Is there a way to feed at least one initial position to this algorithm?

I thought of restricting the `bounds` parameter to the near vicinity of my "solution". This has the drawback that it will affect the *entire* population (`popsize`) and I do want the algorithm to search the entire landscape of solutions.

Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v1.7.0 or newer of [`scipy.optimize.differential_evolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) supports `x0` which is optionally your initial guess.